# Show dialog on widget

Tags: dart, flutter

In flutter, we want to overlay a dialog above the widget.

We were able to display the dialog after pushing the button.

However, we want to display that dialog at the timing of displaying the widget that likes loading dialog.

We implemented as follows.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class XxxxxWidget extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // [NG]We want to show dialog on Container widget.
    // showMyDialog(context);
    return Container(
      child: FlatButton(
        child: Text('Show'),
        onPressed: () {
          // [OK]We can show dialog.
          showMyDialog(context);
        },
      ),
    );
  }

  void showMyDialog(BuildContext context) {
    showDialog<bool>(
      context: context,
      builder: (BuildContext context) {
        return AlertDialog(
          content: const Text(
            'Message',
          ),
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
              },
            ),
          ],
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

When we use [NG] code, the following error occurs.

```
I/flutter (28618): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (28618): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3436:11)
I/flutter (28618): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3462:6)
I/flutter (28618): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1141:14)
I/flutter (28618): #3      OverlayState.insertAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:301:5)
I/flutter (28618): #4      OverlayRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:40:24)
I/flutter (28618): #5      TransitionRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:182:11)
I/flutter (28618): #6      ModalRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:740:11)
I/flutter (28618): #7      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1443:11)
I/flutter (28618): #8      showDialog (package:flutter/src/material/dialog.dart:642:53)
I/flutter (28618): #9      XxxxxWidget.showMyDialog (package:xxxxx/Widgets/xxxxx_widget.dart:20:5)
I/flutter (28618): #10     XxxxxWidget.build (package:xxxxx/Widgets/xxxxx_widget.dart:7:5)
[abridgement]
```

We also tried FutureBuilder but could not solve this problem.

How should we solve this problem?

```
$ flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel beta, v0.5.1, on Mac OS X 10.13.6 17G65, locale ja)
    • Flutter version 0.5.1 at /Applications/flutter
    • Framework revision c7ea3ca377 (3 months ago), 2018-05-29 21:07:33 +0200
    • Engine revision 1ed25ca7b7
    • Dart version 2.0.0-dev.58.0.flutter-f981f09760

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK 27.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/xxxxx/src/android-sdks
    • Android NDK at /Users/xxxxx/src/android-sdks/ndk-bundle
    • Platform android-27, build-tools 27.0.3
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/xxxxx/src/android-sdks
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] iOS toolchain - develop for iOS devices (Xcode 9.4.1)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 9.4.1, Build version 9F2000
    • ios-deploy 1.9.2
    • CocoaPods version 1.5.3

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 27.1.1
    • Dart plugin version 173.4700
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1024-b01)

[!] VS Code (version 1.25.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension not installed; install from
      https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Dart-Code.flutter

[✓] Connected devices (1 available)
    • ASUS Z017DA • XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX • android-arm64 • Android 8.0.0 (API 26)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

We already installed Flutter extension.
But flutter doctor said not installed.
That is not important for this question.

Comment: "• Flutter extension not installed; install from" is a known issue in this Flutter version and safe to ignore.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. We already know about that. :)

Comment: We are using the beta branch. It's a little old. Should we use a different version or master branch to release the application?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

We have to display the dialog once **done** with building the widget.
You can use **Future.delayed** function like below (I **tested**, it is working).

```
class XxxxxWidget extends StatelessWidget {

@override
Widget build (BuildContext context) {
// [NG]We want to show dialog on Container widget.

 Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showMyDialog(context)); // import 'dart:async';
 return Container(
  child: FlatButton(.... //same as question
```

##### Explanation

As Dart is based on *single-threaded event loop*, when we create an async tasks, it will put those events in the end of the event queue and continue its current execution. Please refer below example for more details,

```
void main () {
  print("first");
  Future(() => print("second"));
  print("third");
  Future(() => print("forth"));
 }
```

Output will be

```
first
third
second
forth
```

It is very similar to

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
 print("Async1") //printJob
}
```

Once done with `building the widget` display the `dialog`. Check out my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51965326/flutter-initstate-navigator-is-not-working/51965749#51965749) for similar problem.

Comment: We appreciate your prompt response.
We were able to display the dialog as expected.
You saved our time.

When we tried Future.delayed() before, the dialog was not displayed.
We probably made some other mistake.

Comment: I am also having the similar issue mentioned here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61171869/how-to-show-alert-dialog-in-flutter-without-button-click/61171992?noredirect=1#comment108217005_61171992   The alert shows but it's displaying multiple times whenever build executes. Even on dismissing ok, it will push another one. How could I make sure that only a single alert present in screen in this case or something similar approach would be helpful.

Answer (score 10):

some of this is ambiguous, but you can show an alert dialog in a widgets init method like this

```
Future showDialog() async {

 WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
  await showDialog<String>(
    context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context) => AlertDialog(
          title: const Text('Title'),
          content: const Text('Content')
          actions: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              child: const Text('OK'),
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.of(context).pop();
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
  );
});
}
```

this will wait for the first frame to be drawn before showing the dialog so you can call it from init

```
@override
  void initState() {
   super.initState();

   showDialog();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue you have its normal on Flutter so let's see the code.

I guess the problem is in the constructor for the Widget, need to be like this :

```
showMyDialog(BuildContext context) {
 showDialog(
  context: context,
  builder: (BuildContext context){
  return new AlertDialog(
    content: Text(
        'Message Here',
      ),
      actions: <Widget>[
        FlatButton(
          child: const Text('OK'),
          onPressed: () {
            Navigator.of(context).pop(true);
          },
        ),
      ],
   );
  }
 );
}
```

Try this

Comment: We appreciate your prompt response.
Is BuilderContext a typo of BuildContext?
We fixed it to BuildContext, but the answer was the same as what we tried.
Therefore, the same error was displayed.

It may be only because our knowledge is missing.
We need your detailed answer more.

Answer (score 0):

'The Flutter Way' of doing this would look like this (assume you need to do this when rendering your main screen):

```dart
class MyWidgetWithDialogOnStartup extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: FutureBuilder(
        future: Future.delayed(Duration.zero, () => showMyDialog(context)),
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          return WhateverMyWidgetReallyIs();
        },
      )
    );
  }
}
```

`showMyDialog(context)` wraps the native `showDialog` call.

Comment: is this applicable for my case?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69219115/flutter-showdialog-after-consumer-finish-build