# How to get device IP in Dart/Flutter

Tags: dart, ip, flutter

I am currently writing an app where the user needs to know the IP address of their phone/tablet. Where would I find this information?

I only want to know what the local IP address is, such as, 192.168.x.xxx and NOT the public IP address of the router.

So far, I can only seem to find `InternetAddress.anyIPv4` and `InternetAddress.loopbackIPv4`. The loopback address is not what I want as it is 127.0.0.1.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

I guess you mean the local IP of the currently connected Wifi network, right?

**EDITED**

In this answer, I used to suggest using the [NetworkInterface in 'dart:io'](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/NetworkInterface-class.html), however `NetworkInterface.list` is not supported in all Android devices (as pointed out by [Mahesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10602971/mahesh)). The [wifi](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi) package provides that, but later this was incorporated into the flutter's `connectivity` plugin. In Oct/2020 the methods for that were moved from the `connectivity` to the [wifi_info_flutter](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi_info_flutter) plugin, and in 2021 that package was discontinued in favor of [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus).

So just go for `network_info_plus` and call `await NetworkInfo().getWifiIP()`.

---

By the way, you may also want to check if Wifi is available using the [connectivity_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/connectivity_plus) plugin in [flutter/plugins](https://github.com/flutter/plugins). Here's an example of [how to check if wifi is available](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52175686/796963).

Comment: The NetworkInterface.list works well in Android. I've just tested it on Samsung Galaxy S20 device.

Comment: Yeah `NetworkInterface.list` works for me as well on Android

Comment: Works in some Android devices, but not all of them.

Answer (score 22):

This provides the IP addresses of all interfaces

```
import 'dart:io';

...

  Future printIps() async {
    for (var interface in await NetworkInterface.list()) {
      print('== Interface: ${interface.name} ==');
      for (var addr in interface.addresses) {
        print(
            '${addr.address} ${addr.host} ${addr.isLoopback} ${addr.rawAddress} ${addr.type.name}');
      }
    }
  }
```

See also 
https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/NetworkInterface-class.html

Comment: Wonderful answer. I wanted to get the public facing IP address in our Flutter App. Is it possible to get that directly too, or should I use a service like https://www.ipify.org/?

Comment: If you use a router between your device and the public internet, there is no way to get this public IP from your device without help from some outside service. Such a service gets the information where the connection originates from and can send it back.

Answer (score 16):

I was searching for getting IP address in flutter for both the iOS and android platforms.

As answered by [Feu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411647) and [Günter Zöchbauer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52411510) following **works on only iOS platform**

```
NetworkInterface.list(....);
```

this [listing of network interfaces is not supported for android platform.](https://api.dartlang.org/stable/2.0.0/dart-io/NetworkInterface/listSupported.html)

After too long search and struggling with possible solutions, for getting IP also on android device, I came across a flutter package called [wifi](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/wifi), with this package we can get device IP address on both iOS and android platforms. 
Simple sample function to get device IP address

```
Future<InternetAddress> get selfIP async {
    String ip = await Wifi.ip;
    return InternetAddress(ip);
}
```

I have tested this on android using wifi and also from mobile network.
And also tested on iOS device.

Though from name it looks only for wifi network, but it has also given me correct IP address on mobile data network [tested on 4G network].

**#finally_this_works** : I have almost given up searching for getting IP address on android and was thinking of implementing [platform channel](https://proandroiddev.com/communication-between-flutter-and-native-modules-9b52c6a72dd2) to fetch IP natively from java code for android platform [as interface list was working for iOS]. This wifi package saved the day and lots of headache.

Comment: Any way not to have the user provide specific steps to allow the app to get the IP address from this package on IOS? It seems like a burden for the user

Answer (score 4):

It seems that Dart doesn't have a solution to get your own ip address. Searching for a solution I came across the rest api https://ipify.org to get my public address. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 4):

To get device connected network/WiFi IP you can use [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) package.

For android add the following permissions `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the AndroidManifest.xml file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

IOS permissions are a little more complicated so please read what is requested in the library.

Add package to `pubspec.yaml`

```
dependencies:
  network_info_plus: ^1.0.2
```

Than you can get the current IP by executing

```
String? wifiIP = await NetworkInfo().getWifiIP();
```

Answer (score 3):

Here is another way.

```
 Future<InternetAddress> _retrieveIPAddress() async {
    InternetAddress result;

    int code = Random().nextInt(255);
    var dgSocket = await RawDatagramSocket.bind(InternetAddress.anyIPv4, 0);
    dgSocket.readEventsEnabled = true;
    dgSocket.broadcastEnabled = true;
    Future<InternetAddress> ret =
        dgSocket.timeout(Duration(milliseconds: 100), onTimeout: (sink) {
      sink.close();
    }).expand<InternetAddress>((event) {
      if (event == RawSocketEvent.read) {
        Datagram dg = dgSocket.receive();
        if (dg != null && dg.data.length == 1 && dg.data[0] == code) {
          dgSocket.close();
          return [dg.address];
        }
      }
      return [];
    }).firstWhere((InternetAddress a) => a != null);

    dgSocket.send([code], InternetAddress("255.255.255.255"), dgSocket.port);
    return ret;
  }
```

Answer (score 3):

here, you can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ipify available on pub.dev,

```
import 'package:dart_ipify/dart_ipify.dart';

void main() async {
  final ipv4 = await Ipify.ipv4();
  print(ipv4); // 98.207.254.136

  final ipv6 = await Ipify.ipv64();
  print(ipv6); // 98.207.254.136 or 2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e

  final ipv4json = await Ipify.ipv64(format: Format.JSON);
  print(ipv4json); //{"ip":"98.207.254.136"} or {"ip":"2a00:1450:400f:80d::200e"}

  // The response type can be text, json or jsonp
}
```

Comment: The OP is asking for how to get the local device IP address, not the public IP.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi) package for getting the local IP Address (for eg. 192.168.x.x). (as The NetworkInterface.list (from dart:io) is no longer supporting Android from 7.0 and above).

Use the [wifi](https://pub.dev/packages/wifi) package :

```
import 'package:wifi/wifi.dart';
```

You can retrieve the IP Address like this:

```
Future<String> getIp() async {
  String ip = await Wifi.ip;
  return ip;
}
```

You can display it on a Text widget using FutureBuilder:

```
FutureBuilder<String>(
      future: getIp(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
          return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        } else {
          if (snapshot.hasError)
            return Center(child: Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
          else
            return Center(child: Text('IP Address is : ${snapshot.data}')); //IP Address
        }
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

In my recent app I have a requirement to get user's Ip address and then I found this packgage useful. https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip

Here is How I use it.

```
_onLoginButtonPressed() async {
String ipAddress = await GetIp.ipAddress;
print(ipAddress); //192.168.232.2
}
```

Comment: The get_ip package has been discontinued

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the device_info package?

There is an example on querying device information in https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/device_info#-example-tab-

Comment: device_info has lots of info but not any IP addresses.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus/) plugin to get various info about the wifi connection

Eg:

```
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';

final NetworkInfo _networkInfo = NetworkInfo();

wifiIPv4Addr = await _networkInfo.getWifiIP();
```

For further refernce you can refer to the examples given under the official [page](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus/example)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following package: https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus

And here is the page giving more detail about how to use the package https://plus.fluttercommunity.dev/docs/network_info_plus/usage/#using-network-info-plus

Essentially...if you have the package installed, you would use something like

```
import 'package:network_info_plus/network_info_plus.dart';

final info = NetworkInfo();

var wifiIP = await info.getWifiIP();
```

This package comes with some additional methods that could prove quite useful ;)

NOTE: This package is not supported on flutter web.

Answer (score 0):

If we want to find the public facing IP address of a browser we can use [dart_ipify](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ipify) The example in the documentation worked perfectly for me.

**Import the package:**

```
import 'package:dart_ipify/dart_ipify.dart';
```

**Add this code to `_incrementCounter()`:**

```
final ipv4 = await Ipify.ipv4();
print(ipv4);
```

Answer (score 0):

The flutter [network_info_plus](https://pub.dev/packages/network_info_plus) package provides access to Wifi information such as Wifi IP and name, but the **problem** is that it doesn't work when the phone HotSpot is on and the phone gets its IP from its own HotSpot.

The code below works for any condition and returns local IP whether it comes from phone HotSpot or another router:

```
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

MethodChannel _channel = const MethodChannel('get_ip');
String ip = await _channel.invokeMethod('getIpAdress');
```

Node that in case you got `No implementation found for method` error, you should add [get_ip](https://pub.dev/packages/get_ip/example) package.
I hope it helps.