# How to get client's IP address from angulardart?

Tags: angular-dart

How to get client's IP address from angulardart? I failed to find this out by google.

Comment: Maybe [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52411168/how-to-get-device-ip-in-dart-flutter) could help you.

Comment: @ebelair I read that link. That link is talking about local IP address. But I want to get the remote IP address from the user. I don't think they are the same. Especially, that link is talking about Flutter app, not angulardart. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

As alternative/temporary solution, you can use ipify api to retrieve the ip:

```
var client = new BrowserClient();
var response = await client.get('https://api.ipify.org?format=json');

print('Response status: ${response.statusCode}');
print('Response body: ${response.body}');
```