# Using BLoC in a dialog: Could not find the correct Provider

Tags: flutter, dialog, bloc

I am attempting to use a bloc to manage the content of a dialog.  I am fairly new to flutter.

The page is defined as:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Business Region Manager"),
    ),
    body: MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) =>
              EntityModifyBloc(repository: widget.repository),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => EntityBloc(
              repository: widget.repository,
              modifyBloc: BlocProvider.of<EntityModifyBloc>(context)),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => BusinessRegionBloc(repository: widget.repository),
        ),
      ],
      child: Center(
        child: BusinessRegionPage(widget.business),
      ),
    ));
}
```

Inside BusinessRegionPage I make use of EntityBloc and EntityModifyBloc and, I at least think I have that correct.
The page has a callback that when fired calls a method:

```
void onAddBusinessRegion(){
  showDialog(context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context){
      return BusinessRegionDialog(
        positiveText: "Ok",
        onPositive: onPositive,
        negativeText: 'Cancel',
        onNegative: onNegative,
        businessId: widget.business.id,
      );
    });
}
```

BusinessRegionDialog is a stateful widget and the state implementation build is:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocBuilder<BusinessRegionBloc, BusinessRegionState>(builder: (context, state) {
    if (state is BusinessRegionEmpty) {
      BlocProvider.of<BusinessRegionBloc>(context).add(GetBusinessRegions(widget.businessId));
    }
    if (state is BusinessRegionError) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('Busines Region Error'),
      );
    }
    if (state is BusinessRegionLoaded) {
      return Center(
        child: Text('BusinessRegionLoaded'),
      );
    }
    return Center(
      child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
    );
  });
```

when the callback is fired, I get the message:

Error: Could not find the correct Provider above this BlocBuilder<BusinessRegionBloc, BusinessRegionState> Widget

This likely happens because you used a `BuildContext` that does not include the provider
of your choice.

I made the assumption that in the call to ShowDialog(context), the context is the same one as the one passed into build?  I checked this assumption by printing the hashCode of the context before the showDialog call and after the build implementation on the BusinessRegionPage,

One of the sugestions in the error message was:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Provider<Example>(
    create: (_) => Example(),
    builder: (context) {
      return Text(context.watch<Example>()),
    }
  ),
}
```

so I tried:

```
void onAddBusinessRegion() {
  print("OnAddCallback: " + context.hashCode.toString());
  BusinessRegionClient brClient = BusinessRegionClient(client: http.Client());
  BusinessRegionRepository brRepository =
      BusinessRegionRepository(client: brClient);

  showDialog(
    context: context,
    barrierDismissible: false,
    builder: (BuildContext context) {
      return Provider<BusinessRegionBloc>(
          create: (_) => BusinessRegionBloc(repository: brRepository),
          builder: (context) {
            return BusinessRegionDialog(
              positiveText: "Ok",
              onPositive: onPositive,
              negativeText: 'Cancel',
              onNegative: onNegative,
              businessId: widget.business.id,
            );
          });
    });
}
```

The IDE tells me:
The argument type 'BusinessRegionDialog Function(BuildContext)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Widget Function(BuildContext, Widget)'.

I clearly don't understand something.  All I want to do is fill a dialog with information from a Future from my repository.  Any guidance will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Use `BlocProvider.value` in `showDialog` builder argument.

```dart
onPress: () async {
        await showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (_) {
            return BlocProvider.value(
              value: BlocProvider.of<BlocA>(context),
              child: SimpleDialogWidget(),
            );
          },
        );
      }
```

Answer (score 3):

I finally figured it out thanks to the so entry:

[Flutter: bloc, how to show an alert dialog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53370814/flutter-bloc-how-to-show-an-alert-dialog)

The answer here is to use a stack to have the dialog and the page coexist and the dialog show when the listener has the correct state.  The answer used a StatelessWidget to manage, in the case of the answer, SnackBar.  To be able to add events to the bloc, I used a StatefulWidget.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Business Region Manager"),
    ),
    body: MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => EntityModifyBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository), //widget.repository),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => EntityBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository, //widget.repository,
              modifyBloc: BlocProvider.of<EntityModifyBloc>(context)),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => BusinessRegionDialogBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository),
        ),
      ],
      child: Stack(children: [
        BusinessRegionDialogManager(widget.business.id),
        Center(child: BusinessRegionPage(widget.business)),
      ]),
    ));
}

class BusinessRegionDialogManager extends StatefulWidget {
  final int businessId;

  BusinessRegionDialogManager(this.businessId);

  State<BusinessRegionDialogManager> createState() =>
    _BusinessRegionDialogManagerState();
}


class _BusinessRegionDialogManagerState
extends State<BusinessRegionDialogManager> {

// Callback functions from the dialog so can have access to
// BusinessRegionDialogBloc
void xnPositive(List<Region> addedRegions) {
    BlocProvider.of<BusinessRegionDialogBloc>(context)
      .add(AddBusinessRegions(addedRegions, widget.businessId));
}

void xnNegative(){
}


@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocListener<BusinessRegionDialogBloc, BusinessRegionDialogState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is RegionDialogLoaded) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return BusinessRegionDialog(
              onPositive: xnPositive,
              onNegative: xnNegative,
              regions: state.regions,
            );
          })
      }
    },
    child: Container(),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[i solved it as like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67063459/13760719)

what you have to do is **create a provider of BlocTypeA pass it to child** .create a **dialog with another context2** pass the bloc with provider.value then **build its child with context2** and inside the child widget **access the bloc with previus context .read with BlocTypeA...** hence it is solved

Answer (score 0):

You could use a https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html widget. As explained in the https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDialog.html documentation:

> The useRootNavigator argument is used to determine whether to push the dialog to the Navigator furthest from or nearest to the given context. By default, useRootNavigator is true and the dialog route created by this method is pushed to the root navigator. It can not be null.

By defining a navigator below your providers you can access them in your dialog.

Be carefull, this solution requires you to manage the navigation in your app. For exemple, if you push a new page by using Navigator.of(context) it will get you this one and not the root navigator.

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text("Business Region Manager"),
    ),
    body: MultiBlocProvider(
      providers: [
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => EntityModifyBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository), //widget.repository),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => EntityBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository, //widget.repository,
              modifyBloc: BlocProvider.of<EntityModifyBloc>(context)),
        ),
        BlocProvider(
          create: (context) => BusinessRegionDialogBloc(
              repository: xbrRepository),
        ),
      ],
      child: Navigator( // We add a navigator here
          onGenerateRoute: () => ShowDialogAndNeedsBlocs(),
    ));
}

class ShowDialogAndNeedsBlocs extends StatelessWidget {
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return BlocListener<BusinessRegionDialogBloc, BusinessRegionDialogState>(
    listener: (context, state) {
      if (state is RegionDialogLoaded) {
        showDialog(
          context: context,
          barrierDismissible: false,
          useRootNavigator: false, // Here we set to false
          builder: (BuildContext context) {
            return Container() # Here we can access the blocs
          })
      }
    },
    child: Container(),
  );
}
```