# Flutter snackbar is not showing in the method of the custom class

Tags: flutter

I need to show the snackbar on launch of app in `init` in order to check the connectivity of internet. My code in custom class is:

```
import 'package:connectivity/connectivity.dart';
//import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:system_setting/system_setting.dart'; 

class Network{
   checkNetwork() async {
        var connectivityResult = await (Connectivity().checkConnectivity());
        if (connectivityResult == ConnectivityResult.none) {
          return 
          //print("no internet");
          SnackBar(
              content:  Text("Check internet Connectivity"),
              action: SnackBarAction(
                label: "Settings",
                onPressed: (){
                  SystemSetting.goto(SettingTarget.NOTIFICATION);
                },
              ),
            ); 
            //scaffoldKey.currentState.showSnackBar(snackbar);
            }
} 
}
```

and accessing the method as follows:

```
 @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    //Network.checkNetwork();

    Network objnetwork = Network();
    objnetwork.checkNetwork();
 }
```

I have returned a print statement which was executed right, but when return a widget like snackbar or dialog box, it doesnot appear nor show any exception.

Comment: can you show us the `Scaffold` where you are calling the `initState()` function ?

Comment: @MazinIbrahim i am not calling it in scaffold. ```initState()``` is in ```statefullWidget```

Comment: Where is the code to show the snackbar ?

Comment: @ShyjuM see the question it is in the code above i shared

Comment: @JabirIshaq is that commented code? you are passing the scaffold key to the Network class?

Comment: @ShyjuM i checked it and it also didnot work. i want is, to access this method in init of login page and display snackbar if no internet

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164369/show-alert-dialog-on-app-main-screen-load-automatically-in-flutter found this as alternate, but i need to show this on each page of app through calling a separate class, coz it is bad practise to repeat code on each page

Comment: problem solved https://stackoverflow.com/a/50682918/9091950

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was found to be using `flutter_after_layout` which executes a function after `build` function finishes so the `SnackBar` can be displayed. More explanation is found in this relevant answer about [how to run method when build completes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466556/flutter-run-method-on-widget-build-complete/50682918#50682918) .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52164369/show-alert-dialog-on-app-main-screen-load-automatically-in-flutter found this as alternate, but i need to show this on each page of app through calling a separate class, coz it is bad practise to repeat code on each page

Comment: congratulations !