# SchedulerBinding vs WidgetsBinding

Tags: flutter

Actually I am working on Login page with Bloc. So when I press submit button, it does business logic on bloc then trying to navigate to home page based on the result. I tried this

```
Widget submitButton() {
    return StreamBuilder(
      stream: bloc.submitStream,
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.data == "Success") {
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: (context) => RegisterPage(),
            ),
          );
        }
        return RaisedButton(
          child: Text("Submit"),
          onPressed: () {
            bloc.submitSink.add(null);
          },
        );
      },
    );
  }
```

But I got error like this `The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made...`.

Later then I found two solution: 
1. [Using SchedulerBinding](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/issues/63), 
2. [Using WidgetsBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50806031/open-flutter-dialog-after-navigation/50806950). So what is the difference between SchedulerBinding and WidgetsBinding. Which one do I have to use?

*Full Error Log:*

```
I/flutter (17893): ══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY WIDGETS LIBRARY ╞═══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
I/flutter (17893): The following assertion was thrown building LayoutBuilder:
I/flutter (17893): setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.
I/flutter (17893): This Overlay widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the
I/flutter (17893): process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase
I/flutter (17893): only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework
I/flutter (17893): builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built.
I/flutter (17893): Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
I/flutter (17893): The widget on which setState() or markNeedsBuild() was called was:
I/flutter (17893):   Overlay-[LabeledGlobalKey<OverlayState>#70089](state: OverlayState#3bf13(entries:
I/flutter (17893):   [OverlayEntry#9280a(opaque: false; maintainState: false), OverlayEntry#1af87(opaque: false;
I/flutter (17893):   maintainState: true), OverlayEntry#9fb49(opaque: false; maintainState: false),
I/flutter (17893):   OverlayEntry#87589(opaque: false; maintainState: true)]))
I/flutter (17893): The widget which was currently being built when the offending call was made was:
I/flutter (17893):   LayoutBuilder(renderObject: _RenderLayoutBuilder#d3baf relayoutBoundary=up1 NEEDS-LAYOUT
I/flutter (17893):   NEEDS-PAINT)
I/flutter (17893): 
I/flutter (17893): When the exception was thrown, this was the stack:
I/flutter (17893): #0      Element.markNeedsBuild.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3497:11)
I/flutter (17893): #1      Element.markNeedsBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3523:6)
I/flutter (17893): #2      State.setState (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:1138:14)
I/flutter (17893): #3      OverlayState.insertAll (package:flutter/src/widgets/overlay.dart:301:5)
I/flutter (17893): #4      OverlayRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:43:24)
I/flutter (17893): #5      TransitionRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:184:11)
I/flutter (17893): #6      ModalRoute.install (package:flutter/src/widgets/routes.dart:899:11)
I/flutter (17893): #7      NavigatorState.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1672:11)
I/flutter (17893): #8      Navigator.push (package:flutter/src/widgets/navigator.dart:1011:34)
I/flutter (17893): #9      _SetPinPageState.submitButton (package:technicalreport/screens/set_pin_page.dart:94:15)
I/flutter (17893): #10     _SetPinPageState.build.<anonymous closure>.<anonymous closure> (package:technicalreport/screens/set_pin_page.dart:52:29)
I/flutter (17893): #11     OrientationBuilder._buildWithConstraints (package:flutter/src/widgets/orientation_builder.dart:48:12)
I/flutter (17893): #12     _LayoutBuilderElement._layout.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:111:26)
I/flutter (17893): #13     BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2253:19)
I/flutter (17893): #14     _LayoutBuilderElement._layout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:107:11)
I/flutter (17893): #15     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1728:58)
I/flutter (17893): #16     PipelineOwner._enableMutationsToDirtySubtrees (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:797:15)
I/flutter (17893): #17     RenderObject.invokeLayoutCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1728:13)
I/flutter (17893): #18     _RenderLayoutBuilder.performLayout (package:flutter/src/widgets/layout_builder.dart:205:5)
I/flutter (17893): #19     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #20     MultiChildLayoutDelegate.layoutChild (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:142:11)
I/flutter (17893): #21     _ScaffoldLayout.performLayout (package:flutter/src/material/scaffold.dart:350:7)
I/flutter (17893): #22     MultiChildLayoutDelegate._callPerformLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:212:7)
I/flutter (17893): #23     RenderCustomMultiChildLayoutBox.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/custom_layout.dart:356:14)
I/flutter (17893): #24     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #25     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #26     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #27     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #28     _RenderCustomClip.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:1206:11)
I/flutter (17893): #29     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #30     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #31     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #32     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #33     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #34     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #35     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #36     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #37     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #38     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #39     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #40     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #41     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #42     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #43     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #44     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #45     RenderOffstage.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:3032:13)
I/flutter (17893): #46     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #47     RenderStack.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/stack.dart:510:15)
I/flutter (17893): #48     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #49     __RenderTheatre&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #50     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #51     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #52     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #53     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #54     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #55     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #56     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #57     _RenderProxyBox&RenderBox&RenderObjectWithChildMixin&RenderProxyBoxMixin.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/proxy_box.dart:105:13)
I/flutter (17893): #58     RenderObject.layout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1632:7)
I/flutter (17893): #59     RenderView.performLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/view.dart:151:13)
I/flutter (17893): #60     RenderObject._layoutWithoutResize (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:1507:7)
I/flutter (17893): #61     PipelineOwner.flushLayout (package:flutter/src/rendering/object.dart:766:18)
I/flutter (17893): #62     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:329:19)
I/flutter (17893): #63     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding&WidgetsBinding.drawFrame (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:701:13)
I/flutter (17893): #64     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding&PaintingBinding&SemanticsBinding&RendererBinding._handlePersistentFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/rendering/binding.dart:268:5)
I/flutter (17893): #65     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding._invokeFrameCallback (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:988:15)
I/flutter (17893): #66     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.handleDrawFrame (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:928:9)
I/flutter (17893): #67     _WidgetsFlutterBinding&BindingBase&GestureBinding&ServicesBinding&SchedulerBinding.scheduleWarmUpFrame.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/scheduler/binding.dart:749:7)
I/flutter (17893): #76     _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:382:19)
I/flutter (17893): #77     _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libtimer_impl.dart:416:5)
I/flutter (17893): #78     _RawReceivePortImpl._handleMessage (dart:isolate/runtime/libisolate_patch.dart:171:12)
I/flutter (17893): (elided 8 frames from package dart:async)
I/flutter (17893): ════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
D/        (17893): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0xa0ba6b40, tid 17931
D/EGL_emulation(17893): eglMakeCurrent: 0xa3508c40: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x9084ab40)
```

Comment: Can you show the whole error message?

Comment: Thank ZeRj. I added full error message.

Comment: Technically, you don't need either one. You need to refactor your code. Make your stream a broadcast stream, and add a listener to your stream (probably in the initState lifecycle callback) and navigate to the `RegisterPage` from there. You need to get the offending code outside the build lifecycle.

Answer (score 31):

There are three callbacks available in flutter which rendering flutter widgets.

[image]

As noted in the docs at https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding-mixin.html –

> **Transient callbacks:** triggered by the system’s [Window.onBeginFrame] callback, for synchronizing the application’s
> behavior to the system’s display. For example, [Ticker]s and
> [AnimationController]s trigger from these.
>
> **Persistent callbacks:** triggered by the system’s [Window.onDrawFrame] callback, for updating the system’s display after
> transient callbacks have executed. For example, the rendering layer
> uses this to drive its rendering pipeline.
>
> **Post-frame callbacks:** which are run after persistent callbacks, just before returning from the [Window.onDrawFrame] callback.
>
> Non-rendering tasks, to be run between frames. These are given a
> priority and are executed in priority order according to a
> [schedulingStrategy](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulingStrategy.html).

All above callbacks run sequentially, but for us, the last callback would work i.e Post-frame callbacks

**Widgets Binding:** The glue between the widgets layer and the Flutter engine. which comes with `WidgetsBindingObserver` mixin which has many callbacks but one which required to use is `didChangeAppLifecycleState` that returns AppLifecycleState.

**Scheduler Binding:** This is also similar to WidgetBinding but it does not provide any life cycle callbacks.

The below binding example would be called exactly the ones, means print statement like WidgetsBinding & SchedulerBinding will be printed only once as we called it initState(), but it will be called when build method finished it’s rendering.

```
void initState() {
  super.initState();
  print("initState");
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    print("WidgetsBinding");
  });
  SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
    print("SchedulerBinding");
  });
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Both solutions do the same.

WidgetsBinding inherits this Method from SchedulerBinding
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/WidgetsBinding-mixin.html

It registers a callback that will be called after the frame is build.
See in the docs: 
https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/scheduler/SchedulerBinding/addPostFrameCallback.html